# On icon, p:commandlink results in all records, not current record

Tags: jsf-2.2

In `jsf(xhtml)` screen, 4 records are there. I am swapping the records using jquery, but ordering also should come in sequence way, though the order is also swapping here. When I am giving `p:commandButton` to top arrow icon, it is taking all records, not the current record.

For example:

```
<p:commandButton type="submit" style="display: none" class="abc3" id="abc3" value="#{qc.Name}" >
    <f:ajax listener="#{abcManagedBean.OrderUp(qc)}" render="hiddenId1"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

and I'm calling in `document.ready` (jquery function) as `$('.abc3').click();`

Above, `qc` means it is taking all 4 records, and it should take only current record.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: please ask a co-worker that is not on your project to read this question and have him/her explain what is wrong with it...

Comment: Normally its best to use p:ajax in a primefaces component

Comment: Updated question for clarity and readability